# botframework dialog loop node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I`m writing a bot with botframework. But it seens that this part of the code get the bot stuck in a dialog loop. Where he keep asking the same question.

```
bot.dialog('/DentistaEndereco',[ 
function(session) {
    session.send('Poderia me informar o endereço?', session.message.text); 
    endereco = session.message.text;
    session.endDialog();
    console.log(endereco);

},function(session,results){
    console.log(endereco);
    session.beginDialog('showDentistas');
    session.endDialog();
  }
]);
```

Comment: Please check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to ask a question and based on the visitor's response take an appropriate action.

```
bot.dialog('DentistaEndereco', [
function(session){
    // ask a question to the visitor
    botBuilder.Prompts.text(session, "Poderia me informar o endereço?");
},
function(session, result){
    // get the response from visitor & do something
    console.log(result.response);
    session.beginDialog('showDentistas');
}
]);
```

Hope, this is useful.